# Import JSON object in Google SpreadSheet using Google APP Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I writing a script which calls REST API to get JSON to object as response and then import that JSON object in Google SpreadSheet. I have written the code to call the REST API and get the JSON object. Now I have to write such a code that will write the JSON object in a Google SpreadSheet.
Please see below code:

```
function myFunction() {


    var options = {};
    options.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("username" + ":" + "password")}
    options.muteHttpExceptions=true;


    // var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});

    var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch("url", options);

    var dataAll=JSON.parse(response.getContentText())

    Logger.log(dataAll)

    /*
    var sheet = Sheets.newSpreadsheet();
    sheet.properties = Sheets.newSpreadsheetProperties();
    sheet.properties.title = "Demo";
    var spreadsheet = Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(sheet);
    */
}
```

This is code to call get the JSON object. The lines of code which have been commented out is for calling Google Sheets API.
I want such a script which will import the data in dataAll object, which is JSON object in Google SpreadSheet.

The JSON object is as below:

```
[
{
    "id": 3428,
    "type": "SUPER",
    "firstName": "Nikhil",
    "lastName": "Dingane",
    "loginName": "nikhildingane",
    "domain": "openspecimen",
    "emailAddress": "nikhil@krishagni.com",
    "instituteName": "Krishagni Institute",
    "primarySite": "KSPL site",
    "admin": true,
    "instituteAdmin": false,
    "manageForms": true,
    "cpCount": 0,
    "creationDate": 1586333347000,
    "activityStatus": "Active"
},
{
    "id": 3439,
    "type": "NONE",
    "firstName": "NikhilUpdated",
    "lastName": "Dingane",
    "loginName": "nikhildingane1",
    "domain": "openspecimen",
    "emailAddress": "nikhil.nikhil.dingane@gmail.com",
    "instituteName": "Krishagni Institute",
    "primarySite": "KSPL site",
    "admin": false,
    "instituteAdmin": false,
    "manageForms": true,
    "cpCount": 0,
    "creationDate": 1586427573000,
    "activityStatus": "Active"
}
]
```

I want to write this JSON in Google SpreadSheet

Answer (score 0):

### Assuming that dataAll is a 2D array of values

You can do it is as following with the SpreadsheetApp:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, dataAll.length, dataAll[0].length);
range.setValues(dataAll);
```

References:

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

### How to transform a JSON object into a 2D array

- Use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to access the key-value pairs of each of the JSON array elements
- Use e.g. `map` to transform them into an array
- Assemble the single arrays as desired to set them into the sheet

```
 var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i< json.length; i++){
    var newJson = Object.keys(json[i]).map(function (key) { 
      return [key, json[i][key]]; 
    }); 
    for(var j = 0; j< newJson.length; j++){
      array.push(newJson[j]);
    }
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, array.length, array[0].length);
  range.setValues(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is with the JSON object. Please, have look on the question again I have edited the question, How should I write this JSON array in Goggle SpreadSheet?

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer. I will try it out and then i will inform you.

Answer (score 0):

[`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) is used to the set data as a **two dimensional array** to the sheet. Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and Object.keys with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  to convert array of objects to 2D array.

```js
const data = [
{
"id": 3428,
"type": "SUPER",
"firstName": "Nikhil",
"lastName": "Dingane",
"loginName": "nikhildingane",
"domain": "openspecimen",
"emailAddress": "nikhil@krishagni.com",
"instituteName": "Krishagni Institute",
"primarySite": "KSPL site",
"admin": true,
"instituteAdmin": false,
"manageForms": true,
"cpCount": 0,
"creationDate": 1586333347000,
"activityStatus": "Active"
},
{
"id": 3439,
"type": "NONE",
"firstName": "NikhilUpdated",
"lastName": "Dingane",
"loginName": "nikhildingane1",
"domain": "openspecimen",
"emailAddress": "nikhil.nikhil.dingane@gmail.com",
"instituteName": "Krishagni Institute",
"primarySite": "KSPL site",
"admin": false,
"instituteAdmin": false,
"manageForms": true,
"cpCount": 0,
"creationDate": 1586427573000,
"activityStatus": "Active"
}
];

const out = [Object.keys(data[0]),...data.map(Object.values)];
console.info(out);
//SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange(1,1,out. length,out[0].length).setValues(out)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this approach to fill up the spreadsheet.